# openMP slows down after sched_setaffinity

Tags: linux, openmp

I have a openMP performance issue in my program running on a NUMA machine.

The platform is a 8 core machine. (NUMA with 2 nodes 4 cores each).

There is a function A in my program dose:
1. At the beginning the CPU mask is 0xFF (8 cores)
2. In the middle it calls a child program in background with mask 0xF0 and set the current pid with 0x0F. The function does something in parallel with the child program.
3. After the background child program finishes it joins and do CPU_ZERO to reset binding .

All openMP code without fixed affinity get slowdown after the function A. 
Then I reset it back to 0xFF after function A and it works. The slowdown is gone. 
Does it means mask 0x0 is different than 0xFF for openMP?

To make the question clear. I write a sample code below

Turns out you cannot set no CPU. 
Does it imply unbind CPU means to set the mask to all cpus?

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    cpu_set_t cpu_set;
    int i, ret;
    const int num_cores = get_nprocs_conf();
    CPU_ZERO( &cpu_set );
    ret = sched_getaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );


    printf(" default cpu_set: ");
    for( i=0; i< num_cores; i++ ){
        if( CPU_ISSET( i, &cpu_set )) printf( "%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    CPU_ZERO( &cpu_set );

    CPU_SET( 0, &cpu_set );
    CPU_SET( 1, &cpu_set );
    CPU_SET( 2, &cpu_set );
    CPU_SET( 3, &cpu_set );

    ret = sched_setaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set  );
    printf(" set cpu_set: 0 1 2 3 %s\n", ret==0? "success":"failed" );


    printf(" new cpu_set: ");
    ret = sched_getaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    for( i=0; i< num_cores; i++ ){
        if( CPU_ISSET( i, &cpu_set )) printf( "%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    CPU_ZERO( &cpu_set );

    ret = sched_setaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    printf(" set cpu_set: none %s\n", ret==0? "success":"failed" );

    printf(" new cpu_set: ");
    ret = sched_getaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    for( i=0; i< num_cores; i++ ){
        if( CPU_ISSET( i, &cpu_set )) printf( "%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");

    CPU_ZERO( &cpu_set );
    ret = sched_getaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    for( i=0; i< num_cores; i++ ){
        if( CPU_SET( i, &cpu_set ));
    }

    ret = sched_setaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    printf(" set cpu_set: all %s\n", ret==0? "success":"failed" );

    printf(" new cpu_set: ");
    ret = sched_getaffinity( 0, sizeof(cpu_set), &cpu_set );
    for( i=0; i< num_cores; i++ ){
        if( CPU_ISSET( i, &cpu_set )) printf( "%d ", i);
    }
    printf("\n");




}
```

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information here to answer the question.  How are you setting the cpuset?  Is 0xF0 really a sensible setting with 8 cores?  What are the return codes from setaffinity?

Comment: For 8 core the mask is 8 bit. So it 0xFF for all and 0xF0(0b11110000) for the second NUMA node.

Comment: I set it with CPU_SET and use taskset -p pid to show the mask.

Comment: I was hoping for a bit more detail... It would help people provide answers to your question if you provided a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as described in [ask].

Comment: Hi I added a sample code. It is the function returns false if nothing is set. Sounds like to unbind means all CPU.